# How to add value to object from another object by click in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create shopping cart, when clicking on one of the products its add to shoping cart.
So, I build an Object that contains all products, and another array that 
will contain all clicked item.
When I'm trying to add the value of correct selected item from the products object i'm getting undefined.

```js
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]); app.controller("myCtrl",function ($scope) {

        $scope.products =
            [ 
                { name: 'Apple', price: 5, img: '/Apple.jpg' },
                { name: 'Banana', price: 3.7, img: '/Banana.jpg' },
                { name: 'Grapes', price: 10 , img:'/Grapes.jpg' }
            ];
        $scope.addProduct= function () {

            $scope.products.push({name:$scope.nameProduct, price:$scope.priceProduct, tmuna:$scope.imgProduct});
            $scope.nameProduct = "";
            $scope.priceProduct = "";
            $scope.imgProduct = "";

        };
        $scope.cartList = [{ name: 'Apple'}];
        $scope.addToCart = function () {
            $scope.cartList.push({name:$scope.nameProduct});
            $scope.nameProduct = "";

        };


    });
```

```html
        <div class="dropdown pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Shopping Cart <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1"  ng-repeat="product in cartList">
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" >{{product.name}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <form >
            <p>Product: <input type = "text" ng-model = "nameProduct"></p>
            <p>Price: <input type = "number" ng-model = "priceProduct"></p>
            <p>Image: <input type = "text" ng-model = "imgProduct"></p>
            <input type = "submit" value = "Add" ng-click = "addProduct()">
        </form>
        
        </div>
        
        <div class="product" ng-repeat="product in products">
            <img ng-src="{{product.img}}" />
            <div class="name">{{product.name}}</div>
            <div class="price">${{product.price}}</div>
            <p class="badge" ng-click="addToCart()">Add to<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're calling `addToCart()` the function uses what's on `$scope.nameProduct`, but that's an empty string. You cleared it on `addProduct()` function.

Pass the name of the product you're adding:

```
ng-click="addToCart(product.name)"
```

And change your function accordingly:

```
$scope.addToCart = function (productName) {
     $scope.cartList.push({ name: productName });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the product object in the addToCart function like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lyrjp92z/

JS

```
$scope.addToCart = function(product) {
  $scope.cartList.push({
   name: product.name
 });
};
```

HTML

```
<p class="badge" ng-click="addToCart(product)">Add to<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></p>
```

Also note, that passing in the product object and not just the string will allow you to also pass in the price, which you can calculate a total from.

Comment: What's the point of adding another answer which is not different from the one that's already posted?

Comment: It is different actually.

Comment: The only difference is that you're passing an object reference and then taking the name in the function, which changes nothing.

Comment: Relax.  I'm not sure why you're all bent out of shape about this.

Comment: The whole point is to help to OP. If you enter a post and there's an answer that you think is correct, vote it up. If you want to change a little thing, drop a comment. If it's bad, vote it down. If you have a whole different approach, then by all means - post a different one. That's my take anyway, otherwise it's just polluting the thread.

Comment: 1. I was working on the fiddle and posted my answer before I saw yours.  2. You are going to waste a lot of time being the answer police because this happens all the time.  3.  They're different approaches to the question.  Mine provided a working example along with a different solution.

Comment: Thanks Guys, but if I have more then just 3 variables, 
do i need to pass all of the vars names and separate them with a comma?

Comment: @Maor, no, you can just pass the object and access the object properties in your controller function or in your cart list.  That's the plus side for using an object rather than strings.  Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/h6ysveef/

Comment: @Maor Pass whatever you need. If you ask me, just push the object to your array, don't recompose it.